# The system cannot find the path specified. '-Xmx1000M' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

After I installed java version "1.8.0_171" and started running hadoop-3.1.0 , i try to install pig-0.17.0 by the following steps:

1.Downloaded Pig from https://downloads.apache.org/pig/pig-0.17.0/(download pig-0.17.0.tar.gz )

2.Extracted the tar file by right click extract file location (after extraction C:\pig-0.17.0)

3.Set environment variable
PIG_HOME C:\pig-0.17.0
path C:\pig-0.17.0\bin

4.Go to C:\pig-0.17.0\bin edit pig.cmd and save it

```
::set HADOOP_BIN_PATH=%HADOOP_HOME%\bin
set HADOOP_BIN_PATH=%HADOOP_HOME%\libexec
```

5.After following all this step go to command prompt => `cd C:\pig-0.17.0\bin TYPE:pig or pig -version;`

It shows the ERROR: The system cannot find the path specified. '-Xmx1000M' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Also i'll do the same steps for pig-0.16.0 it also shows the same error..

Please help!